# Exception in thread "main" org.apache.Hadoop.mapred.InvalidJobConfException: Output directory not set in JobConf

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am a new Hadoop user. My program is to skip bad record data in mapreduce. I didnot skip bad data so firstly, I am not trying to skip data and I want to find the which error occur. So, I add mycustomrunjob() to know why I cannot skip bad record. Currently, I deleted skip coding line. I have a problem when I running this program although I already set output file path:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.* ;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.* ;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.* ;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.* ;

public class SkipData
{  
public static class MapClass extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, LongWritable>
{
 private final static LongWritable one = new LongWritable(1);
private Text word = new Text("totalcount");
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, LongWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException
{
String line = value.toString();
if (line.equals("skiptext"))
throw new RuntimeException("Found skiptext") ;

output.collect(word, one);

}
}
public static RunningJob myCustomRunJob(JobConf job) throws Exception {
JobClient jc = new JobClient(job);
RunningJob rj = jc.submitJob(job);
if (!jc.monitorAndPrintJob(job, rj)) {
  throw new IOException("Job failed with info: " + rj.getFailureInfo());
}
return rj;
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "/");
Configuration config = new Configuration() ;
JobConf conf = new JobConf(config, SkipData.class);
RunningJob result=myCustomRunJob(conf);

conf.setJobName("SkipData");

conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
conf.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);

conf.setMapperClass(MapClass.class);
conf.setCombinerClass(LongSumReducer.class);
conf.setReducerClass(LongSumReducer.class);

FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf,args[0]) ;
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1])) ;

JobClient.runJob(conf);
}
}
```

I am trying to accomplish this error many times. I use old API .How can I solve this?

```
18/02/28 11:05:28 DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation:  PrivilegedActionException as:saung (auth:SIMPLE) cause:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidJobConfException: Output directory not set in JobConf.
18/02/28 11:05:28 DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: PrivilegedActionException as:saung (auth:SIMPLE) cause:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidJobConfException: Output directory not set in JobConf.
Exception in thread "main"  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidJobConfException: Output directory not set in JobConf.
 at  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(FileOutputFormat.ja va:117)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.checkSpecs(JobSubmitter.java:268)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:139)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1290)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1287)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
 at  org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1746)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1287)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:575)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:570)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
 at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1746)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:570)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:561)
 at mapredpack.SkipData.myCustomRunJob(SkipData.java:90)
 at mapredpack.SkipData.main(SkipData.java:140)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to run the job twice - by calling

```
RunningJob result=myCustomRunJob(conf);
```

so early on, your job will fail as none of the configuration is set at that stage. I would remove that line (and the `myCustomRunJob(JobConf job)` method). The `JobClient.runJob(conf)` at the very bottom will deal with running the job.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues are there in the code.

1. You are calling the job for first time without setting any
   input/output path.
2. Also, you are trying to resubmit job, which is
   bound to fail (because each MR job needs a new output directory).

Change your main method like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "/");
Configuration config = new Configuration() ;
JobConf conf = new JobConf(config, SkipData.class);

conf.setJobName("SkipData");

conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
conf.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);

conf.setMapperClass(MapClass.class);
conf.setCombinerClass(LongSumReducer.class);
conf.setReducerClass(LongSumReducer.class);

FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf,args[0]) ;
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1])) ;

RunningJob result=myCustomRunJob(conf);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still have this problem. How can I solve this?

Comment: Could you please update the post with the latest code after my suggested changes and error details?